# Japanese character missing from email

Tags: codeigniter, email, utf-8

I am using codeignator framework for my project.Some Japanese character are missing from email when delivered.I checked the controller and all charcters are present.I checked config, email charaset and found it is utf-8. I also added this "header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');" .  Also there is no problem for mails sent from the same project, problem exists only for this particular email.

public function email()
      {

```
                if($this->lan == "en"){

                $site_name      = "xyz.com";
                $fromname           = "xyz.com";
                $subject            = 'sub 【'.$site_name.'】';
                $content            = " Content of email from ".$site_name."<br /><br />";
                }else{

                $site_name          = "japanesename.com";
                $fromname           = "japanesename.com";

                header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

                $subject            = 'japanesesub【'.$site_name.'】';
                $content            = "

                                     jp content".$site_name."<br />";
                }

        $to                 = $email;
                $this->load->library('email');
                $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
                $this->email->from($fromemail,$fromname);
                $this->email->to($to);
                $this->email->subject($subject);
                $this->email->message($content);
                $this->email->send();
                redirect('redirect_url');
}
```

Comment: More details! Where is the text coming from? How is it inserted into the email? How are you sending the email? As many details as you can provide, please!

Comment: Take a look at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/46cb4626-716f-4fd7-af49-4b6fe1e5b955/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the header, instead you need to set the charset config before you start your other email code:

```
// Set mail config variables
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Furthermore you will have to encode any strings to `UTF-8`, even if you expect they are already utf-8 encoded.

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8");
```